# Eclipse RCP Hide Installations Details in About Window

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have a custom RCP application,
Do you know how to hide the **Installation Details button** from the About Dialog ??

[image: The about window]

Comment: @JosephElcid Yes It is. The issue is that I just call the command "org.eclipse.ui.help.aboutAction" To show the Dialog. But I not sure how to customize it and delete that button.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found the way to hide that button, I think the only possibility is to extend AboutDialog and make a new command for your plugin.

```
public class DAboutHandler extends AbstractHandler {


private class DAboutDialog extends AboutDialog
{
    public final static int DETAILS_ID = IDialogConstants.CLIENT_ID + 1;
    public DAboutDialog(Shell parentShell) {
        super(parentShell);
    }

    @Override
    protected Button createButton(Composite parent, int id, String label, boolean defaultButton) {
        if(id==DETAILS_ID) return null;
        return super.createButton(parent, id, label, defaultButton);
    }
}
/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see org.eclipse.core.commands.IHandler#execute(org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionEvent)
 */
public DAboutDialog execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    new DAboutDialog(HandlerUtil.getActiveShellChecked(event)).open();
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Another alternative instead of extending the `AboutDialog` is to extend the base `Dialog` and put your own About content in it.

Comment: You are right, but I think this is the best way if you just want to hide this button. ^^

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can ... the Installation Details button is created in the AboutDialog createButtonsForButtonBar method ... and it looks like it's unconditional.